# Why is this ajax post giving me an error? Does an ajax post require "true" or "false" to be returned?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/cc/validate",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data: JSON.encode($parts),
    complete: function(){
    },
    success: function(n)
    {
        console.log(n);
        console.log(n.object);
        console.log("ajax complete");
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("error");

    }
 });
```

- This gets an array defined above the ajax post call and posts an encoded json                             array to a php file. The problem is determining why the post will only let me return "true" or "false". If i try to return any string, i get the error in the ajax. I want to be able to return a string created in the php and not only "true" or "false".

Comment: I think it is the Same Origin Policy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem since the files originate from the same site. If this was the problem, do you know a fix?

Comment: If this is a file from the same site you might want to try the relative path in the `url` and see if that helps

Comment: Are you saying that this section: success: function(n) { alert(n); } would alert a TRUE or FALSE to you? If that is so, perhaps your PHP script has a debug variable dump left over somewhere that returns TRUE/FALSE instead of what you expect. Otherwise, it would be helpful if you pointed out to exactly where does it return TRUE/FALSE, as there are 3 places in that script that could return this (namely complete, success and error functions).

Comment: The ajax gives an error when either nothing is echoed in the external php file or any string that is not TRUE or FALSE. However if I echo "true" or echo "false", the ajax has success. My problem is that i do not want to be limited to only returning TRUE or FALSE but any string.

Comment: The php file is empty other than the echo line:

Comment: What is the error you get on the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1):

are you on a local host? well if so you might have to change your mime headers (application/json) ... your javascript is expecting json but your php is echoing html.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

if you want to be able to return something else then json you have to delete or change the content type in your ajax call. the content type is for giving jquery a hint of what to expect from the server. if you tell it will receive json data you need to give it json or you'll have a parse error.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. In addition to this fix, I also discovered that since I was not returning a json array, I needed to take out the dataType: "json" in my ajax call. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

your code is alright
just make sure your php file return an echo json_encode($arrayOFdata)

> dataType:"json",

means the data recived from php will be parsed as a json object

it doesn't mean you will send a json object